# Flutter keep client alive doesn't wrok

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that switches widgets on a page.
(custom made container with 2 gestureDetectors to switch between the 2 pages)

the stateless widget to switch the pages: (it returns the chosen widget)

```
  class Layer2 extends StatelessWidget {
  Layer2({this.pageName});

  PageSelect pageName;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (pageName == PageSelect.Friends) {
      return DiscoverFriends();
    } else if (pageName == PageSelect.FriendRequests) {
      return Requests();
    } else {
      return Text("");
    }
  }
}
```

Then I use this stful widget where I added the 'keep alive client'.

```
class Requests extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RequestsState createState() => _RequestsState();
}

class _RequestsState extends State<Requests>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Requests> {

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

etc....

It works, but it doesn't keep the 2 widgets alive. (when I switch, the init state runs again)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you switching?

Comment: I 'switch' with a gesturedetector, it does 'setState' and adjusts the PageSelect. Is it possible that am doing the wrong approach to switch pages? Are there better ways to use a sort of TabBar with custom layout?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should understand the lifecycle of Flutter. If you call the widget with navigator you get a new one, so if you want to call the same, I mean the previous one, you should use 'Navigator.pop' function.